# Spring MVC http 404 not found, any ideas how?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

http://localhost:8080/AnchorMail/ works and goes to the index.jsp as it should.

http://localhost:8080/AnchorMail/greeting causes a HTTP status 404 not found.

It should be going to a hello JSP page, I believe. I'm new to this and any help would be so appreciated. Thank you.

the controller below

```
   @Controller
    public class HelloController {

        @RequestMapping(value="/greeting")
        public String sayHello(Model model) {

            model.addAttribute("greeting","Hello World");

            return "hello";
        }

}
```

servlet-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.Controller"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property  name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property  name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>anchorMailServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>anchorMailServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

</web-app>
```

Pom.xml below

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>AnchorMail</groupId>
      <artifactId>AnchorMail</artifactId>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>AnchorMail Maven Webapp</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <finalName>AnchorMail</finalName>
      </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: Do you have a hello.jsp file?  What is the controller's package?

Comment: @DwB Hi, I have a controller package called com.Controller and that has the HelloController.java file. I also have a hello.jsp file in a folder called jsp in WEB-INF

Comment: What is the name of the war file you are installing into the JEE container?

Comment: I'm new to web development and i'm not sure what a JEE container is

Comment: How are you running the application?

Comment: in a Tomcat server.

Comment: Check the tomcat logs for information.  these are in the log directory in the tomcat installation.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this configuration element:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>anchorMailServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Pay attention to the configuration that you created.

Requests that end in *.html are forwarded to your spring dispatcher servlet.

`http://localhost:8080/AnchorMail/greeting` does not end in `.html`

Also, try changing the url-pattern to `/*.html`.

Comment: i changed it to /*.html in the urlpattern tag. It resulted in server failed to start.  I was following a tutorial step by step in creating this and it didn't work lol

Comment: read the error log from the tomcat or whatever JEE container you are using.  It will tell you the problem (not always super helpful).

Comment: SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AnchorMail]]

Comment: the above is what I get when I change it to /*.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/greeting.html")

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property  name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/> //other name then >>jsp
    <property  name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: pointing out the mistake and providing some description of what these configurations do is a better approach